# As a student, how can I negotiate comfortable and appropriate sleeping arrangements with a stranger for a conference?

Tags: interpersonal-issues, travel, correspondence

I'm an undergraduate student that was offered a role researching for a grant. I was able to get authorship status on a paper and will be attending a conference for it later this year. The professor I am working for connected me with another student at a different university in order to share a hotel room. We will both be staying for the entire week and are responsible for booking our own reservations. Unfortunately, the centre the conference is located at is booked, with only a single-bed room available that we would be required to vacate on Wednesday then move back in.

This student was fine with booking the room and asked me if I was okay with it, but after I realized that it is a very small, dorm-like room with a small bed and no futon I counter-offered a reasonably-priced room at another hotel a half-mile away with two beds that we would not need to move out of midweek. I thought this would be well-received, however the student pushed back saying that the other room had a better price (of course, as it was intended for one person or a couple) and we would have better involvement with the conference (doubtful, as long as we show up on time).

Besides already being an incredibly poor sleeper, I'm otherwise just uncomfortable sharing a small bed with another student I don't know, and the room is small enough that I can't confidently say a hotel cot would fit. However, I also don't feel comfortable making this a bigger conflict than necessary, and I don't want to upset my professor by costing our grant more money than necessary by booking my own room at twice the cost. On the other hand, I do feel I have the right to request sleeping accommodations that I am comfortable with. How can I handle this appropriately without offending anyone?

Comment: Would a hotel even allow two people to share a single room? I think you are well within your rights to ask for a bit more money to get a double room.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [interpersonal.stackexchange.com](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @atronat the OP said it's a single bed designed for a couple, so it's not a single person.  It's often possible to request a cot, which I think may be the easiest solution, and whoever gets the cot pays a smaller share since it's likely more uncomfortable, but I agree with problemofficer that it's better suited for IPS

Comment: And IPS referred me to Academia on the chance that someone here has had a shared experience.

Comment: My 2 ct: dump this cheapskate professor. But why did you ask that other student about the other hotel? Is he paying for himself?

Comment: A quick tip - get on the waiting list at the hotel for two-bed rooms. Also - have you let the professor know there are not two-bed rooms available at the hotel?

Comment: @Karl that seems extremely premature. There's nothing in the OP that even indicates the professor is aware of the conflict.

Comment: @Jared who would be paying for the room?

Comment: @beldaz I am unsure via his end, however my bill was being payed for by the university via the grant. We would have told the hotel at check-in to split the bill in half.

Comment: @Jared that's what I figured. I think the other student is being overly precious about the cost their university would pay. Hold your ground and go with Nicole's answer.

Comment: I'd say that the "share a bed with a stranger" thing is non-negotiable and completely inappropriate. Sharing a *room* with a stranger would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You don't mention what country you're in and perhaps it might matter, that what's acceptable in one country might not be in another.  Here in the US, it's not uncommon to be asked to share a room at a conference or in other professional situations with another attendee of the same sex.  But it would never be considered appropriate to ask anyone to share a bed.  Never.  Period.  It would only happen if a supervisor, e.g., your department chair was unaware it was happening.

So, if you're here in the US, I would be firm.  Send an email to your professor, pointing out that sharing a room is okay, but sharing a bed is not and insist on your solution, the room with two beds at the other hotel.  I would not feel guilty even for one second about the extra cost.  You're entitled to your own bed.  If your professor insists you share a bed, I would report this to your department chair and request help.

Comment: Agree. In fact, OP probably doesn't even need to explain that sharing a bed is not okay, it's enough to just say "the room we were looking at only has one bed, so looks like sharing it won't work. I proposed this other, double room half a mile away, but the other student didn't go for that. What do you think?"

Comment: While I agree with your answer, I'm confused about something: are you saying there are countries where it would be reasonable to be asked to share a bed with a stranger?

Comment: @Kimball That's not what he said. `If US` -> `not OK` does not imply `If Not US` -> `OK`. And as long as one does not know cultures of *all* countries around the globe, I strongly support using the qualifier.

Comment: @FooBar The answerer (who I guess is a she) indicates a belief that it actually is different in different countries, though they didn't spell out what part depend on the country.  I would be surprised (and interested to know) if there are countries where the "sharing a bed with a stranger" aspect is acceptable.  Hence my request for clarification.

Comment: @Kimball My qualifier was as innocuous as yours, "guessing" I'm a she.  From my picture and name, you shouldn't have to guess.  I tend to add them defensively here on this site because anytime I don't, I can pretty much count on someone jumping on me for forgetting that the US is not the only country in the world. In this particular case, I'm not aware of any differences, but it seemed possible that in extremely poor countries, perhaps one might be asked to share a bed.  And perhaps there are very wealthy countries where it'd be unthinkable to be asked to share a room.

Comment: Actually, I don't agree that "sharing a room is ok" if the OP finds it uncomfortable. This is an intensely personal situation and no one should object if the person wants to maintain privacy for _any_ reason or no reason at all.

Comment: Don't be coerced into a situation that is against your principles or your personal sense of self. I realize that the prof may have been trying to be helpful, of course, but the decisions aren't for him or her to make.

Comment: @Kimball the answerer never implied that it was different in different countries, she pointed out that the US is the only region she's familiar enough with to give an answer and that she's aware that social norms vary from place to place. She's saying *she doesn't know* how it works in other places, not that *she knows it's different*.

Comment: I'll note here that the OP hasn't been part of the comments. I haven't actually read anywhere that the professor is "insisting" on his solution. However, I agree with your suggestion in the case that he is. It may just be he is trying to be helpful. It could also be that he thinks for whatever reason that the two people would find value in some association. But all that matters, in my view, is the comfort of the OP in the situation.

Comment: @Buffy Okay, fixed.  "continues to insist" → "insists".

Comment: Why is sharing a room ok? It can be disgusting, snoring, smell, bathroom privacy, ...

Comment: AlexandreAubrey and @FooBar: I think Kimball has a point. While of course US->OK does not imply NONUS->NONOK, this kind of thinking needs one to be comfortable with mathematical reasoning (which is a skill obtained eg in STEM-studies). In conversation with non-stem people (which are also hopefully also in the audience of this site), it might, depending on the context, be better to write explicitly ("and I don't know the situation for other countries" (as N. Hamilton did in the comments)).

Answer (score 18):

> The professor I am working for connected me with another student at a different university in order to share a hotel room.

I think this is the key point. The professor, who is your supervisor and is in charge of the grant funds, is sending you to the conference, and *it is their responsibility to ensure you have safe, reasonable accommodations during the trip.* Their proposed solution involving shared accommodations with the student they connected you with might have seemed reasonable when they suggested it, but it is becoming clear that it isn’t. Certainly asking that you share a hotel bed or other uncomfortably close quarters with a complete stranger is way outside the norm in almost all areas of academia (the only exceptions I can think of being a few disciplines like archaeology, paleontology and such where hardy researchers sometimes go on field studies in very spartan environments), and not something you should be expected to accept as a condition for attending a conference.

The conclusion is simple. You should email the professor, explain that you have not been able to find an acceptable arrangement to share accommodations with the other student, and ask him to help you find an alternative solution involving an acceptable level of comfort and privacy. Such a request, if phrased politely, would be completely reasonable and professional, and I’m sure any half-decent professor would not be fazed by it or have any trouble addressing the problem.

Good luck, and have fun at the conference.

Comment: This, except for the part of asking the supervisor to help you find an alternative solution. Email him the details of a single room you found online (rather cheap, for you alone) and ask if that would be okay or ask if he knows other students who are interested in finding a shared room.

Comment: @Sabine agreed, thanks, it’s indeed a good idea to proactively suggest an alternative solution.

Answer (score 17):

You may just need to come to the conclusion that no negotiation is possible and make your own arrangements. No one should be offended by someone who wants to preserve their personal space and privacy.

I doubt that your professor, who is the only one, other than yourself who matters much here, would think less of you if you don't yield to a situation you find somewhere between uncomfortable and untenable.

There is the financial issue of course, but your privacy is likely worth the cost and you will have a much better experience at the conference if you are comfortable personally. While cost isn't a factor for me anymore I often tell family (cousins, kids, etc) I'd rather get a hotel than use their guest room. Privacy, comfort, personal space.

That said, you might take a bit of time at the conference to see if the other student is someone you might want to be friends and colleagues with generally, but that is a question for the future.

---

Due to a comment, perhaps I should be more clear and explicit. This is not something you should accept if you have any reservations. You are perfectly correct to reject it.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know this person, but I would simply say it honestly. It's perfectly professional. Say something like "I understand that the room is a bit more expensive, but I would much rather find a room that accommodates two people and does not force us to share a bed. This room is the best I could find, but if you can find a similar one for a better price, send me a link."

This is a perfectly normal and reasonable thing to want, it places no obligation on you to pay a greater share, and it should not offend any person who is there in a professional capacity.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I think being even more firm in saying that you don't want to share a bed would be a good idea. Just say, "I am not willing to share a bed" in there somewhere.

Comment: @sgroves Can do that too, although it shouldn't be necessary. My guess is that most people would get the point from this. It takes quite an unpleasant person to insist on sharing a bed in this situation.

Comment: "Would much rather" doesn't get the point across; it makes it sound like you're okay with either, but prefer one option to the other. Need to be clear that sharing a bed is not an option.

Comment: @R.. As i said, I think it does get the point across - but, as I also said, being more firm is probably fine. Which one you would rather use may depend on what kind of person you believe you are dealing with.